# Why does sulfonation of aniline occur para rather than ortho?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, amines, regioselectivity

According to a textbook by K. L. Chugh:

> Sulfonation [of aniline] is a reversible reaction. The *p*-isomer, being more stable, does not get desulfonated easily. Hence, *p*-sulfanilic acid is the major product.

I am curious as to why the *ortho* isomer (2-aminobenzenesulfonic acid) is not more thermodynamically stable. There is a possibility of intramolecular hydrogen bonding (in a six-membered ring):

[image: Intramolecular hydrogen bond in 2-aminobenzenesulfonic acid]

Why is the *para* isomer (4-aminobenzenesulfonic acid) favoured?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sulfonyl group is kind of bulky due to the size of the sulfur, so steric hindrance is probably making it energetically disfavored for the group to be placed *ortho*. It's unlikely you can see this easily from a [model](https://embed.molview.org/v1/?mode=vdw&cid=8479&bg=gray) or a drawing. If you have access to computational resources, you might be able to see the issue.