# Reversible Sulfonation of Aniline?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

If I have aniline in acid and fuming $\ce{SO3}$, will it reversibly sufonate? I am worried that the nitrogen will be protonated and reduce the nucleophilicity of benzene ring to the point where sulfonation just isn't possible and instead you just get a salt? Or is it possible that you only get mono-sulfonation?

Here is my reaction scheme:

[image]

Comment: [See this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65162/why-does-sulfonation-of-aniline-occur-para-rather-than-ortho). Quoting: "Sulfonation [of aniline] is a reversible reaction. (However) The p-isomer, being more stable, does not get desulfonated easily. Hence, p-sulfanilic acid is the major product."

Answer (score 3):

It sulfonates on N first and then rearranges on heating to give sulfonation in the 4 position. JACS **68** (1946) 969