Sulfonation of aniline: is a meta-direction possible?
The nitration of aniline with a standard nitrating mixture (HNO3 and H2SO4) has been taught as a classic example of 'consider all factors before arriving at a prediction in chemistry.' One expects an ortho/para product due to the high electron densities at said positions. However, one recieves another, at first baffling, product: meta-nitroaniline. And not in any small percent either! It is almost a 50-50 ratio between para and meta isomers. Even on this very website there have been questions asked about this, for example this.
It was taught that this is due to the protonation of the aniline group, making an anilinium ion that is instead electron-withdrawing instead of electron releasing, leaving the meta position dense of electrons. One acknowledges that this step has to be the first step in the formation of the meta product.
However, no such mention of an anilinium ion forming has been provided for the sulfonation of aniline. We were told it yields para and ortho isomers, and para and ortho isomers only. It is not evident to me why this is the case. We are using a very strong acid, H2SO4, along with sulfur trioxide, to sulfonate aniline. Should the same logic not apply? Aniline is protonated to form the anilinium, which instead becomes a meta director instead of an ortho/para director. One has made a photo to help explain one's reason.

A simpler example was considered: phenol. Why this does not happen with phenol is maybe because of the differences in electronegativity between oxygen and nitrogen. This is not satisfactory, however what is even less satisfactory is why there is no mention of any meta-anilinesulfonic acid that is produced by a protonation, when all that has been changed is one reactant in the mixture. There is still aniline, and still sulfuric acid, so there should be anilinium formed in this reaction too, which should lead to the meta product in some (noticeable percent).
The thought is incredibly puzzling! One has tried to come up with a reason on why this does not happen. One has come up empty handed. Attempts have been made for information on this reaction far and wide on the internet, and have found no such answer. So: why do we not obtain meta-anilinesulfonic acid when sulfonation conditions are used on aniline? What prevents it from forming? Is there an intiution one may use so as to recieve a complete picture and 'consider all factors' before arriving at an answer?  And if, on the off chance, one is correct about the formation of meta-anilinesulfonic acid, why is it not mentioned anywhere in literature or textbooks alike?

I don't know the answer for sure, but I suspect it is due to the one major difference between the nitration and sulfonation reactions: nitration is irreversible hence kinetically controlled, while sulfonation is reversible and thermodynamically controlled. I imagine the ortho/para products are thermodynamically more stable (due to push/pull resonance forms), so it could well be that the meta product forms initially but ultimately reverts to the SM and reacts to give the thermodynamic products.

Possible when fuming sulfuric acid is used: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/152874/17368

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75745/reversible-sulfonation-of-aniline
